# How to add if not tagname exiftool

Tags: exiftool

I am looking to use exiftool to add modification date.  I want to do something like exiftool if not modificationsdate thwn write date not. How to would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Find a file that has your "modificationsdate" already set.  Use [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) to figure out the exact name of that tag.  You would then use exiftool's [`-if` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#if-NUM-EXPR) to check to see if the tag exists or not.

`exiftool -if "not $TAG" <RestOfCommand>`

Replace TAG with the actual tag name you found from above.

If this command is run under Linux/Mac/Powershell, swap the double for single quotes to avoid the dollar sign as being interpreted as the start of a shell variable.

Comment: I am  combining  it with exiftool-overwrite_original -ModifyDate=now

Comment: Then change TAG to `ModifyDate` above and use the  rest of your command.

Comment: I get the error file not foubd -exiftool

Comment: I am running this as the command

Exiftool -if "not $ModifyDate" exiftool -overwrite _original -ModifyDate=now filepath. 

When running it i get error 
file not found - "
file not found -exiftool

Comment: That's because you put a second "exiftool" in the command.

Comment: Would this work Exiftool -if "not $ModifyDate" overwrite _original -ModifyDate=now filepath