# Print a message if a field is undefinied using exiftool

Tags: exiftool

I want a script to print out a warning message if a certain field is left blank. This answer seems to do what I want, but I cannot get it to work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69885820

This is what I tried:

```
exiftool -if "not Iptc:Caption-Abstract" -p 'ImageDescription missing in $filename' -s3 .
```

Thanks!

Comment: You dropped the dollar sign. `exiftool -if "not $Iptc:Caption-Abstract" -p 'ImageDescription missing in $filename' -s3 .`  Change the double quotes to single quotes if you're using Mac/Linux/Windows Powershell.

Comment: Also, you can remove the `-s3` as it does nothing when using the [`-p` (`-printFormat`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#p-FMTFILE-or-STR--printFormat).

Comment: Thanks. It may be a bug. ```exiftool -if 'not $Iptc:City' -p 'City missing in $filename' .``` works, but the same fails with ```Caption-Abstract```. Maybe this is due to the dash.

Comment: The dash is required for the `Caption-Abstract` tag.  [Example](https://i.imgur.com/15Zj3BX.png) of command working with `Caption-Abstract`.

Comment: OK. This was a bug in Lightroom. It seems to put the previous value in some fields during export, when I deleted the content of the field.

Comment: You might check other tags.  `XMP:Description` is the corresponding tag for `IPTC:Caption-Abstract` in XMP.  Also, be aware of the difference between IPTC IIM/Legacy tags (IPTC in exiftool) and IPTC Core/Ext tags (which are XMP tags).